# XSLT: Display choice field value

Tags: web-part, document-library, xslt, variable

I am editing ItemStyle.xsl to display documents in a web part. I need to display the value of a choice field whose name unfortunately contains a forward slash and I don't get it to display its value. So far I tried:

`<xsl:value-of select="@Slash_x002f_Column"/>`
`<xsl:value-of select="Slash_x002f_Column"/>`

I even tried to create a variable using

`<xsl:variable name="SlashColumn" select="Slash_x002f_Column" />`
`<xsl:variable name="SlashColumn" select="@Slash_x002f_Column" />`

and thus

`<xsl:value-of select="$Slash_x002f_Column"/>`

The column has two choices, so nothing too strange. Some attempts even rendered the whole page unusable. What do I need to do?
Thank you

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "choice field" but if it's an XML (or HTML) element or attribute, then its name can't include a "/" (and if it isn't, then XSLT can't select it). It would help to show us your input.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed this is a Sharepoint site so my comment merely betrays my ignorance of Sharepoint.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I didn't know that XSLT was actually that difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours of struggle I finally found the solution to my problem:

`<xsl:value-of select="@SlashColumn" />`

this means that SharePoint is apparently contracting the internal name and omitting the slash (`_x002f_`) in the internal field name (`Slash_x002f_Column`).

What actually happened if I had a field with the internal name `SlashColumn`?